# Springboot 2.0 https enable with SSL certificate from CA

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, https, keytool

I have small springboot app. I need use HTPPS and I buy SSL certificate from CA with embedded tomcat.
I try to config it.
application.property:

```
#https server properties
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:https/keystore1.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
```

p.12 created with keytool

```
keytool.exe -import -alias tomcat -file C:\**\*.crt -keystore C:\**\resources\https\keystore1.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -storepass password
```

**.crt I get from CA. I have a private key too, but don't know where I need use it here.

When I try to start this app I have an error

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:255) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:300) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) [spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at xmpptelegram.XmppTelegramApplication.main(XmppTelegramApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1021) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Alias name [tomcat] does not identify a key entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:116) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:87) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Alias name [tomcat] does not identify a key entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:229) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

2018-04-02 11:20:16.662  INFO 15988 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-04-02 11:20:16.674  INFO 15988 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-04-02 11:20:16.678 ERROR 15988 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8443 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8443, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

Why app doesn't see alias? I see it in keystore.

May be I need some another settings for use https in springboot tomcat? All instructions only about use celfsinght certs...

Comment: was any solution found for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be importing the entire CA reply to the keystore, not just the signed certificate. This will probably be a p7b or p7r file. What you did will only add the certificate as a trusted certificate. It will not associate the certificate chain to your private key.

You need to edit your `-file` argument (provide the right file here).

Answer (score 0):

Had to dig in a lot to get this to work.

This works for all those who have got a certificate from certificate authority.

This is because the **.p12** is not generated properly.

You need **openssl** for this.

In **windows**, you can go to Gitbash and type : **winpty openssl**

Execute the below command:

```
pkcs12 -export -in yourcert.cer -inkey yourkey.key -out keystore1.p12
```

It will ask for a passphrase: This is the value in **.secret** file.

It will ask for an export password: give anything you want, for example exportpassword

In Your **Spring Boot App**, put the generated **keystore1.p12** in the resources folder.

In **application.yml** file, configure like below:

```
server:
  port: 7878
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: classpath:keystore1.p12
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store-password: exportpassword
```