Trusted SSL certificate for Spring Boot API
Where do I get a trusted SSL certificate and how do I insert that in my Spring Boot API?
I am an Angular Frontend Developer and currently expand my skills and learn Spring Boot 3.
I successfully developed a REST API.
My Angular app and Spring Boot API work well on my local machine.
But on my production server, the browser gives me an error message stating that my frontend app is served on HTTPS and that I am trying to reach an API that is served on HTTP, which is not allowed.
So I googled a lot and found a way to switch the API to HTTPS.
I did the following:
I executed the command
keytool -genkey -alias https_cert -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 365

Then I copied the "keystore.p12" file to my Spring Boot Project in the "resources" Directory.
And then I put the following in my Spring Boot file "application.properties":
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=myPassword
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=https_cert

Where I used the password that I entered when I executed the "keytool" command as myPassword.
Again on my local machine that works well and my Spring Boot API was served on HTTPS.
After I transferred my Spring Boot App to my production server, the API works well with POSTMAN.
But the browser with my Angular App gives me again an error and says that there is a problem with the certificate.
So I googled again and found out that the certificate that I am using is a self-signed SSL certificate.
When I put the address of my API in the browser, the browser says that this is an unsafe website. If I tell the browser that I trust the website, the API is reached. After that, the communication of Angular Frontend and Spring Boot Backend works well.
However, a normal user would not put the address of the API in the browser and accept it as a trusted website.
I figured out that I need a trusted certificate and everything should work well.
I googled again, but could not find information that I could understand.
So my question is now, where do I get a trusted certificate and how do I insert that in my Spring Boot API?
One additional information: My production server runs on Ubuntu 24.04

Before proceeding, you WANT to understand how SSL/TSL works and why its needed. It is a key security concept all web developers should be aware of. There is extensive documentation on them to varying levels (For instance, I found this article digestible). You can get certificates for a price and there are free options available too, but again, you really want to understand what you are chewing into.

@Jetto Martínez
Alright, I have read this article. So it says that I can generate with the "openssl" command 2 files, a private key (server.key) and a CSR (server.csr). These 2 files I have to send to a recognized Certificate Authority (CA). I have to pay for that and they will return me a .crt file (my certificate).
But before I pay anything, I would like to know what I have to do with this .crt file.
Can you help me with this? Or can you recommend an article? Or is it the same procedure that I do with my self-signed certificate(keystore.p12), like I wrote in this StackOverflow-Question?

Java handles certificates with keystores, while most (if not every) CA handles crt files. Java has methods to import those certificates into the keystore, but Tomcat (In case you are deploying from a WAR file) can handle both ways. If your Spring project lives in a different machine/box, you could use a proxy server like Apache or Nginx and certify it instead of Spring itself... You need to do your due diligence and research, because security is never a copy-paste thing. From the article, you'll want to look for installation instructions, and then, spring/java specific instructions.

For instance, I found this fairly similar question to yours, here in SO.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607950/springboot-2-0-https-enable-with-ssl-certificate-from-ca

I solved my problem now. I went to the website https://www.sslforfree.com/ and got a 90-days-certificate for free.
I got 3 files: "ca_bundle.crt", "certificate.crt" and "private.key".
Then I copied the files to my JAVA "resources" directory.
Then I added the following to my JAVA "application.properties" file:
server.port=8443
server.ssl.certificate-private-key=classpath:private.key
server.ssl.certificate=classpath:certificate.crt

And now everything works well like I want.
It's just a 90-days-certificate, but for learning Spring Boot it is enough. I think I can get a certificate for longer time if I pay on that website.
@Jetto Martínez Thanks for your time and help.
